# Is it possible to achive low error on MNIST using Random Ferns?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, naive-bayes

I'm new in machine learning and i want to study how to use random ferns.

I read this paper [Fast Keypoint Recognition in Ten Lines of Code](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/126376/files/OzuysalFL07.pdf) and implement simple version of algorithm.

But then I tried to run this algorithm on MNIST dataset (without any pre-processing) I achieved only 7.5% error rate. 
I created 40 ferns and 40 pairs of points for each fern. I chose random subset of training data to train each fern (it improves error rate a little)

I suppose that 7.5% is not really bad result. But i was able to achieve 3% by simple Random Forest (CART)

So my question is: How i can improve this error rate and is 7.5% ok for Random Ferns?
I do not want to obtain cool digits classifier but i want to know is my implementation works well and how to improve Random Ferns.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [discriminative ferns ensembles](https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCAQFjAAahUKEwjB-ND-o9HIAhXm_HIKHTteAWk&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cv-foundation.org%2Fopenaccess%2Fcontent_cvpr_2014%2Fpapers%2FKrupka_Discriminative_Ferns_Ensemble_2014_CVPR_paper.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGheQPqViIYyHRKbmuCmA1pO5NRCQ&sig2=G0udwrdk6E1PPDwdaz5kjg&bvm=bv.105454873,d.bGQ). Basically they train the classifier by minimizing a Hinge loss similar to that minimized by SVM's.

This way they improve the accuracy of classical ferns for the MNIST database.